# How to redirect page php page on 123-reg to remove end "/"

Tags: php, html, display

My current webpage is listed in Google as `http://www.rg-s.co.uk/suvatcalculator.php/`.

Due to the fact it has the end `/`, the CSS does not load correctly. Yet when I access the page normally via `http://www.rg-s.co.uk/suvatcalculator.php`, the page loads fine.

Is there a way I can redirect the page with `/` to the correct page using 123-Reg?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I think the problem you should be trying to solve is why Google has you listed with a `/` at the end of your URL. I'm not sure redirecting would fix that, and could just make your page load slower in the end.

Comment: @Nathan, you are right, but if some user have the wrong bookmark an redirect as fallback should work.

Comment: @Thomas, good point.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]) && !empty($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"])
{
  $protocol="http";
  if(isset(_SERVER["HTTPS"]))
  {
    $protocol="https";
  }
  header ("Location: $protocol//{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}/{$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]});
  exit; 
}
```